# How to optimise the broadcast join in spark which is taking 4 to 5 hrs to complete?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

Im Doing broaddcast join in spark
Table A is around 2.5 MB and
Table B is Around 10 GB

Query:

```
SELECT /*+ BROADCAST(a) */ a.col1,
       b.col2,
       b.col3,
       b.col4
FROM Table_A a
FULL OUTER JOIN Table_B b
ON a.id=b.id AND a.bucket_id=b.bucket_id;
```

Spark Config im using:

```
--Tag : # --executor-memory 12g 
--executor-cores 2 
--conf spark.reducer.maxReqsInFlight=1 
—conf spark.shuffle.useOldFetchProtocol=true 
—conf spark.shuffle.io.retryWait=60s 
—conf spark.shuffle.io.maxRetries=10 
—cong spark.network.timeout=800 
--conf spark.driver.memory=2g 
--conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=2g 
--conf spark.reducer.maxSizeInFlight=128m 
--conf spark.maxRemoteBlockSizeFetchToMem=256m 
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=600 
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=2048m" 
--conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=8000 
--conf spark.shuffle.compress=true 
--conf spark.io.compression.codec=zstd --conf spark.io.compression.zstd.level=2
```

I tried to tweak the executor memory ,partitions from 6000 to 8000 and incresed memory overhead 1gb to 2gb. But still its taking the same amount of time.